# Bond : Difference between coupon and yield

Tags: investing, bonds, terminology, yield

On a bond chart, I always see the terms: `Yield` & `Coupon`, which seem to mean the same thing. What is the difference between these two terms?

[image]

Comment: Notice that if the Bid is greater than 100, the yield is lower while if the Bid is lower than 100, the yield is higher.

Answer (score 6):

`Coupon` tells us the rate of returns(%) for the bonds **when it was first issued** based on **issue price**

`Yield` tells us the rate of returns(%) for the bond based on **current price**

Assuming a bond was issued at $1000 , promising to pay $50 yearly , it has a coupon rate of 5% & yield of 5%. However, if due to unforseen circumstances the bond price drops to $500, it still has a coupon rate of 5% but the yield is currently 10%.

Coupon (%) = Returns / Issue Price * 100

Yield (%) = Returns / Current Price  * 100

Comment: Take a look at the YLD in OP's picture. It's not Returns / Current Price * 100. Else how does that zero coupon have any yield? That column is a YTM, Yield to maturity, which is a bit more complex, but takes the difference from today's price to face value into account.